# redmine : due date remainder not migrating

Tags: redmine, bitnami, redmine-plugins

I am currently developing a project management system using Bitnami Redmine. I am using Redmine 1.4.7.

I found a plugin on https://github.com/f0y/due_date_reminder/tree/redmine-1.4 which I want use on my project. I copied the plugin to `C:\BitNami\redmine-1.4.7-2\apps\redmine\htdocs\vendor\plugins`. I followed the instructions provided but when I try to install the plugin it does not get migrated.

I'm running this command in `C:\BitNami\redmine-1.4.7-2\apps\redmine\htdocs`:

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate_plugins rails_env=production
```

and receive the following error:

```
Expected C:/BitNami/redmine-1.4.7-2/apps/redmine/htdocs/app/models/user.rb to define User
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate_plugins => environment
See full trace by running task with --trace
```

I don't get what is the problem with the `user.rb` file. Please help.

Comment: 1. use `RAILS_ENV` instead of `rails_env`. 2. add flag `--trace` to see more details. So run `bundle exec rake db:migrate_plugins RAILS_ENV=production --trace` and post the output

Comment: Thanks gotva for the help. I solved my migration problem from
http://www.redmine.org/boards/2/topics/8819